# Summation question concerning the formula $P(\cup^n_{k=1}A_k) = \sum^n_{k=1}(-1)^{k-1}p_k$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, summation, inclusion-exclusion

Note $p_{k}=\sum_{1 \leq i_{1} < i_{2}  \dots < i_{k} \leq i_{n} } P(A_ {i_{1}} \cap A_ {i_{2}} \cap  \dots \cap  A_ {i_{k}})$ prove $P(\cup^n_{k=1}A_k) = \sum^n_{k=1}(-1)^{k-1}p_k$

This question uses a result from a previous question, it says that,

> by developing the last term in the result (2) :
>
> $ \mathbb{1}_{ \cup^n_{k=1} A_k } = 1 - \prod^n_{k=1}( 1 -\mathbb{1}_{A_k} ) \dots (2) $
>
> we get :
>
> $ \prod^n_{k=1}( 1 - \mathbb{1}_{A_k} ) = 1 - \sum^n_{k=1} (-1)^{k-1}\sum_{1 \leq i_{1} < i_{1} \dots < i_{k} \leq i_{n} }$  $ \mathbb{1}_{
> A_{ i_{1} } \cap A_{i_{2}} \cap  \dots \cap  A_{i_{k}  } }$
>
> using linearity of expactation we get: $P(\cup^n_{k=1}A_k) = \sum^n_{k=1}(-1)^{k-1}p_k$

Remark included in the solution at the end : you also need to notice that $E( \mathbb{1}_{A} ) = P(A)$

Now my problem in order to understand this proof, I need to understand how this double summation works because what I come to is, by the inclusion exclusion theorem :

$P(\cup^n_{k=1}A_k) = \sum^n_{k=1}P(A_k) + (-1)^{2+1} P(A_{i_{1}}\cap A_{i_{2}}) + (-1)^{3+1} P(A_{i_{1}}  \cap A_{i_{2}} \cap A_{i_{3}} )+ \dots + (-1)^{n+1}P(A_{i_{1}} \cap \dots \cap A_{i_{n}} ) $

How does this summation work so that it is equivalent to :
$P(\cup^n_{k=1}A_k) = \sum^n_{k=1}(-1)^{k-1}p_k$

How does it gets out the $\sum (-1)^{k-1}$ to sum then over the $p_{k}=\sum_{1 \leq i_{1} < i_{2}  \dots < i_{k} \leq i_{n} } P(A_ {i_{1}} \cap A_ {i_{2}} \cap  \dots \cap  A_ {i_{k}})$ and why k-1 ?

I first thought of $\sum^n_{k=1}P(A_k) = 1$

I spent enough hours trying to get myself an illustration of what is happening using  the [definitions of double sums](https://fr.wikiversity.org/wiki/Sommation/Sommation_double) but I dont get the right result

Comment: You can't just consider $\Pr(A_1\cap A_2)$, for example.  You have to consider all possible pairs of events.  That's where $\sum \Pr(A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2})$ comes from.

Comment: You surely have seen : exclusion-inclusion principle as presented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: $k$ appears as an exponent in place of an index at some spots.

Comment: @saulspatz Ah I see thank you , I will correct that. Even by correcting I don't get how the required summation comes out

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry for that mistake, I'll correct it thank you

Comment: If it were me, I'd take a step back and review how to relate coefficients of a monic polynomial with the roots (eigenvalues) in factored form.  The machinery you need to understand is called elementary symmetric functions or elementary symmetric polynomials.  For now just assign $\lambda_k := \mathbb{1}_{A_k}$ i.e. treat them as formal symbols, and focus on $q(x) = (x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)...(x-\lambda_n)$ then specialize to $q(1)$ later. Also helpful to recall the complement of union of events is the intersection of complements

Comment: @user8675309 Thank you for your comment, I'll take a moment to get my head around what you wrote

Comment: @user8675309 Oh these are concept I don't quite understand now and that need time probably, so my question in fact should have been why is $ \prod^n_{k=1}( 1 - \mathbb{1}_{A_k} ) = 1 - \sum^n_{k=1} (-1)^{k-1}\sum_{1 \leq i_{1} < i_{1} \dots < i_{k} \leq i_{n} }$  $ \mathbb{1}_{
A_{ i_{1} } \cap A_{i_{2}} \cap  \dots \cap  A_{i_{k}  } }$ ?

Comment: What I can't tells is whether there is also an issue with your understanding of indicators/bernoulis.  You should consider $n=2$ case. $(1 - \mathbb{1}_{A_k} ) =  \mathbb{1}_{A_k^C}$ so  $(1 - \mathbb{1}_{A_1} )(1 - \mathbb{1}_{A_2} ) =  \mathbb{1}_{A_1^C}\mathbb{1}_{A_2^C}$ and the product of bernoulis is a bernouli and this takes on the value 1 only when $A_1^C \cap A_2^C$.  For now I would focus on factoring and expanding monic polynomials and using elem sym functions -- this will pay dividends in many different areas of math.

Comment: $v :=\begin{bmatrix} 
\mathbb 1_{A_1} \\ 
\mathbb 1_{A_2}\\ 
\vdots \\ 
\mathbb 1_{A_n} 
\end{bmatrix}$  

if it were me, I'd negate and add one to your (2) and focus on the complementary event (i.e. of intersections of complements -- the last line in my first comment).  This restates your problem as  

$\mathbb 1_{A_1^C \cap .... \cap  A_n^C} = \prod_{k=1}^n (1-\mathbb 1_{A_k}) = e_0(v) - e_1(v) + e_2(v)-... +(-1)^n e_n(v)$  
with $e_k$ the kth elementary symmetric function.  But again using $\lambda_k := \mathbb 1_{A_k}$ and just focusing on the algebra is what's key here

Comment: hmmmm thank you so much for this answer , I am starting to see some light I'll work on that a bit